# Iterate over all DOM elements including added elements

Tags: php, dom

I have this method that loops through all nodes:

```
public function processNode(DOMNode $element){
    if($element instanceof DOMElement){
        foreach($element->childNodes as $node){
            // Adds child nodes and/or modifies the current node
            $this->editNode($node);
            if($node->hasChildNodes()){
                $this->processNode($node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I think that when nodes are added within the `editNode()` method, this doesn't pick them up and process those nodes as well.

Is there a better way for me to loop through all nodes including nodes that have been added via `editNode()`?

Comment: If you're able to prepend/append some nodes as siblings of `$node` passed into `editNode`, it won't be solved even with `liveliness` of `childNodes`. Is it possible to reorganize your code so no such changes will be introduced?

Comment: Probably not, as I have added a attribute called `repeat` which looks like this `<div repeat="i in value"><div scope="i.title"></div></div>` which loops through an array and repeats the inner div for as many items as there are in the `value` array.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like doing a `for` instead of a `foreach` is a better way to go. I was then able to process the items that were getting skipped when using the `foreach`.

```
public function processNode(DOMNode $element){
    if($element instanceof DOMElement){
        $nodes = $element->childNodes;
        for($i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++){
            $node = $nodes->item($i);
            $this->editNode($node);
            if($node->hasChildNodes()){
                $this->processNode($node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```